# Import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

Tags: import

I am trying to setup OpenLayers on my computer, and am following the directions here: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/bundle.html

When I try to run it in my browser I get error:
import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

How do I fix that?

index.js:

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import {Map, View} from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';

const map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    })
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 0
  })
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error clearly states that somewhere in your `.js` files there is an import statement:

```
import something from 'some-package'
```

And that import statement is not at the very top of the module e.g.:

```
someExpressionHere(); // This must be moved below import statement
import something from 'some-package'
```

UPD:
After chatting with OP, the actual problem was not building the project (not bundling), when there was a css module import.

Comment: it says its on index.js, line 1. But I'm jusing the index.js here: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/bundle.html. Which begins with four import statements.

Comment: Can you provide exact texts of the error and index.js file

Comment: Well its just an empty browser screen with console.log providing: SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module index.js:1

Comment: Can you also provide index.js' first lines

Comment: Well i'm just using hte exact files here: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/bundle.html. It's the index.js one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183817/discussion-between-nurbol-alpysbayev-and-hermann-ingjaldsson).